# Data Labels for Line Chart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, linechart, label

I want to add data labels to the below coding somebody help me out!
[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMHe4.png) and i want to have my output image like this... [this is what i want like labels over the points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhqbj.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
year=[1955,1960,1965,1970,1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2016,2017,2018]
ind=[1.69,1.89,2.06,2.15,2.34,2.32,2.33,2.17,2.00,1.86,1.67,1.47,1.24,1.15,1.13,1.11]
china=[1.96,1.49,1.90,2.68,2.23,1.54,1.50,1.83,1.13,0.69,0.59,0.57,0.54,0.46,0.43,0.39]
plt.plot(ind,color='red',label='India',marker='o', markerfacecolor='red', markersize=6)
plt.plot(china,color='blue',label='China',marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=6,)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(year)),year,rotation=90)
plt.title("Population Comparison")
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Rate of Increase in Population(%)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: question is not very clear what you mean by data labels, i think you may be looking for annotations  [link](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html). Please clarify exactly what you're after.

Comment: wait i update my question and help me dude

Comment: @DarrenBrien help me bro now see the images i added